# Alamofire request doesn't work inside a method but the same request works inside a controller | Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, swift3, request, response, alamofire

In my app I've got one class called User and this class has the method "login", the method login is only a request to my API but it doesn't work when I call it from the controller. If I copy the same code into my controller it works.

This is my method:

```
    func login () -> Void {
    Alamofire.request("myUrl", method: .post , parameters: ["nick": "myNick", "pass" : "myPass"] , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON{ response in
        let status = response.response?.statusCode as! Int
        switch status{
            case 200:
                let data = response.data
                let utf8Text = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
                self.token = utf8Text
                break
            default:
                break
        }

    }

}
```

This is my controller:

```
    @IBAction func loginFunc(_ sender: Any) {
    var usuario = User(nick:"myNick", pass:"myPass",token:nil)
    usuario.login()
    if  usuario.token == nil{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "¡Vaya!", message: "Ese nombre de usuario o esa contraseña son incorrectas", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    print(usuario.token!)

}
```

It always print nil but the server return the correct token

Comment: The request is async. It means `print` runs before you got response.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `completion` block :

```
func login (completion : ()->()) {
    Alamofire.request("myUrl", method: .post , parameters: ["nick": "myNick", "pass" : "myPass"] , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON{ response in
        let status = response.response?.statusCode as! Int
        switch status{
        case 200:
            let data = response.data
            let utf8Text = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
            self.token = utf8Text
            break
        default:
            break
        }
        completion()
    }
}

@IBAction func loginFunc(_ sender: Any) {
    var usuario = User(nick:"myNick", pass:"myPass",token:nil)
    usuario.login {
        if  usuario.token == nil{
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "¡Vaya!", message: "Ese nombre de usuario o esa contraseña son incorrectas", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        print(usuario.token!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func login (_ completion: ((Response) -> Void)) -> Void {
    Alamofire.request("myUrl", method: .post , parameters: ["nick": "myNick", "pass" : "myPass"] , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON(completion)
}
```

**Now you can show your alert controller like this:**

```
@IBAction func loginFunc(_ sender: Any) {
var usuario = User(nick:"myNick", pass:"myPass",token:nil)
usuario.login { [weak self] response in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    let status = response.response?.statusCode as! Int
    switch status{
    case 200:
        let data = response.data
        let utf8Text = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
        strongSelf.usuario.token = utf8Text
        break
    default:
        break
    }

    print(usuario.token!)

    if  usuario.token == nil {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "¡Vaya!", message: "Ese nombre de usuario o esa contraseña son incorrectas", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: 
UIAlertActionStyle.default))
        strongSelf.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
  }
}
```